# htaccess redirection to /blog removing www from all locations

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress blog on `/blog` which is configured to run without www. so the blog url is: `http://domain.com/blog/`

I need to redirect all traffic from:

```
www.domain.com
domain.com
www.domain.com/*
domain.com/*
www.domain.com/blog/
www.domain.com/blog/*
```

So that that the root goes to the blog and any www. that have been added or are incorrectly configure will be stripped.

I do not seem to be able to configure the .htaccess file in the root `/` and in `/blog/` to work.

Answer (score 0):

These rules should do the job (although some REAL testing is required as I was just simulating all URls):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add trailing slash in /blog if absent 
RewriteRule ^blog$ http://domain.com/blog/ [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
# redirect to /blog/ on domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain.com
RewriteRule ^(?!blog/?)(.*)$ http://domain.com/blog/$1 [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
# redirect to /blog/ on www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(blog/)?(.*)$ http://domain.com/blog/$2 [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
```

If some URL does NOT redirect then let me know (FULL URL) so I can look into it.

Comment: No that did not work, only the domain.com to domain.com/blog/ the www part is not working.

Comment: 1) What URLs **exactly** are not working (provide a few)? 2) Where did you put these rules (which htaccess) ?